# How can I set as "auto" a control size by C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I want to set as "" the size (width and heigth) of an element such as a TextBox" by C# but I can't.

I've to try anything as the following but it doesn't work:

```
TextBox1.Width = double.NaN;
```

I want to know hoy can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you can see here: [WebControl.Width Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.width.aspx) the property is of type Unit, so you can do this for example:

```
TextBox1.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
```

look at the methods and constructor of the [Unit Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx) for more examples.